# What does it mean by putting dots into a struts forward tag?

Tags: java, jsp, frameworks, struts, tags

As the example below, I came across this one when reading the source code of [JAVA D.I.Y Forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdforum/).

```
<forward name="feedback" path=".page.index.feedback"/>
<forward name="group" path=".page.index.group"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm finding it hard to see the source for JAVA D.I.Y Forum (it seems to only be available in a RAR file, and I'm not installing something just to look at it), but I would guess that the project is using [tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/). Somewhere there should be a tiles configuration file which tells the application how to build the view.